# Making animations in Android

Tags: android, animation

I have 5 years experience in many programming languages and recently I've started making android apps. Windows' forms taught me nicely how to manage everything, so "pure programming" part is not hard. However, it's problem when it comes to animations because in that I have no experience, although I have some basic experience with Photoshop.

I was searching for how to start with animations, but what I usually find is some basic tutorial of how to flip text and I wouldn't like to have not-organized learning because it usually ends with many holes in knowledge.

So, could you recommend me some book or some series of tutorials to start animations with, which would give me better understanding of what's happening and how to make application full of graphical interaction?

Comment: Might see this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229901/is-there-any-useful-android-animation-tutorial-for-beginners][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229901/is-there-any-useful-android-animation-tutorial-for-beginners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lars Vogen has an excellent tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidAnimation/article.html). Also the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html) is a good place to look.
There is a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229901/is-there-any-useful-android-animation-tutorial-for-beginners) as well which could help.

Another good resource is the samples which can be found in `sdk\samples\{android-version}`, look for `apidemoes` as it contains a bunch of simple examples to learn from.